# Rails routing for pretty urls and get variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, get, pretty-urls

Rails noob here

I have a url "/products?sports=2", which shows the products fine. But I want the url to be "/volleyball"

I currently have, which I know is completely worng:

`match 'volleyball' => 'products?sports=2'`

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) which is covered in this [RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid).

Comment: Also, [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730) covers many configurations which you could find useful. I had to place it in reply because I can not post more than 2 links per reply.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Comment: Thanks gregates..This seems to work for me actually

<code>match 'volleyball' => 'spree/products#index', :defaults => { :sports => '2' }</code>

Answer (score 0):

You may want the following route:

```
get ':sport_id', :to => 'products#show'

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render text: "sport is #{params['sport_id']}"
  end
end
```